# NodeJS (JavaScript/TypeScript) - Error while reading Parquet file

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, parquet

I am trying to read parquet file with nodejs:

```
var parquet = require('parquetjs');

(
    async () => {
    try {
            // create new ParquetReader that reads from 'fruits.parquet`
      let reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openFile('f1.snappy.parquet');

        // create a new cursor
        let cursor = reader.getCursor();

        // read all records from the file and print them
        let record = null;
        while (record = await cursor.next()) {
            console.log(record);
        }

      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error while reading a parquet file:\n', e)
      }

    }

) ();
```

Getting error:

```
error while reading a parquet file:
 invalid page type: DICTIONARY_PAGE
```

Same parquet file - I can read with Python pyarrow library without issue..

What can be the reason?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix it somehow? @user9750148

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue (and some others when reading nested objects) with parquetjs

I switched to https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs-lite and now everything works smoothly

parquetjs-lite is a fork of parquetjs so I didn't need to change any of my code